# MVC specific routing without prefixing routes

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, routes

I have got a strange issue at the moment where I am working on a project which as only 1 route which is a default route:

`routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}"
    defaults: new { controller: "SomeController", action: "SomeAction" }
);`

Now they cannot change this default route as *everything works* however now I have an issue where I am working on a prototype of an existing bit of functionality, they refused to do it in a separate branch so I am stuck working on mainline. Ignoring all of these constraints I wanted to isolate our new work into its own url as I want to start trying to be restful in the routing and response types, so this is me carving out a bastion of sanity amongst the crazy.

Now to isolate our stuff I added the following route:

`routes.MapRoute(
    name: "SanityRoute",
    url: "my-module/{controller}/{action}/{id}"
    defaults: new { controller: "Dashboard", action: "Index" },
    namespaces: new [] { Namespace.To.My.Isolated.Controllers }
);`

So all of my new stuff would be within the `/my-module` prefixed url, however this didn't work as I put it after the `Default` route, which meant the default was still catching it (I put the route debugger on to prove this), so I thought well I will put my route above the default one to make it more specific, after all the other routes would be something like:

`http://some-url/SomeController/SomeAction`

Not

`http://some-url/my-module/SomeController/SomeAction`

This seemed to work, brilliant I thought, however then I noticed that all other routes were being prefixed with `my-module`, which seems odd. So I would go to login `/` (root url) which was fine, then the redirected login would take me to `my-module/SomeControllerNotInMyModule/SomeAction` so it rendered the correct controller outside of the scope of my module however it kept prefixing the route so everyone else was a bit confused.

So I am a bit puzzled as to why is MVC prefixing all routes with `my-module` as it is only specified within the route url, I would assume the LACK of this prefix on controller routes outside of my module would keep me isolated.

Any ideas?

Comment: How are you navigating to the URL? By typing it in a browser, redirecting to an action, redirecting to a route, something else?

Comment: It depends on which url you mean, there is a login page which redirects to some other index page within the system, I do not know where the code for that lives I think it is nestled amongst a 6000 line controller. That is the entry point into the system and the first route which prefixes with `my-module`, if you mean the other routes that I have added they are manual urls as the front end is knockout driven with dynamic templates so it does not make use of the `@Html.ActionLink` etc functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am a bit hesitant to class this as "THE" answer, but it is the answer which has got me up and running, the issue seems to stem from with the above routing configuration the `ActionLink` based calls seem to prefix `my-module` onto everything, I still do not know why, it seems that either MVC is trying to be clever and force the routes to match the prefix of the first route (which seems odd) or this project somewhere has some custom URL re-writing magic (Which I cannot find anywhere and I don't know how that could effect an `ActionLink` call on a page anyway).

Anyway to solve the issue I have put the default route back up top as the highest scoring and put a constraint on it that the controller != 'my-module'. Which looks like:

`constraints: new { controller: "^((?!my-module).))*$" }`

I am still a bit baffled by it all, as routing should be a rule to match urls, not a rule to enforce them. Anyway this has got me moving on again.

Answer (score 0):

As per I understand I think you are using Area for creating my-module.
If not show please refer "Organizing an ASP.NET MVC Application using Areas"
May be this will happen because of miss configuration.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee671793(v=vs.100).aspx

Hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: I am not explicitly using areas, I just want to isolate my controller away from the others, so I just added the prefix to filter them. To my knowledge you can do this as routing is just a pattern matcher really which delegates to a controller.

Answer (score 0):

As per your code I it's working perfect because you added two route in Config file.

---

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}"
    defaults: new { controller: "SomeController", action: "SomeAction" }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "SanityRoute",
    url: "my-module/{controller}/{action}/{id}"
    defaults: new { controller: "Dashboard", action: "Index" },
    namespaces: new [] { Namespace.To.My.Isolated.Controllers }
);

Error : Both behave like default URL. So when you are working on like 
http://www.website.com/mymodule/SomeController/SomeAction
and try to redirect to other URL route will allow that URL because you put as default.

### Try below code will work..

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "DashboardRoute",
    url: "myModule/Dashboard/{action}",
    defaults: new { action = "Index" }
);

Thank you

Comment: Problem there is I would need to explicitly specify every single controller within that module, which is not the end of the world however it is more code to maintain and change should someone want to rename the route etc. I would only expect the default one to behave like a default as the other has a prefix which is not classed as a dynamic var, so it should surely only match something which starts with `my-module` however it is making the `ActionLink` on views generate this prefix which seems incorrect behaviour.